# java conditional operator for exceptions

Tags: java

```java
private static int testReturn(final boolean flag) {
    return flag ? 1 : 2;
}

private static void testThrow1(final boolean flag)
    throws IOException, SQLException {

    if (flag ) {
        throw new IOException("IO");
    } else {
        throw new SQLException("SQL");
    }
}
```

When I tried to change it with `?:` operator,

```java
private static void testThrow2(final boolean flag)
    throws
        //IOException, SQLException, // not even required
        Exception {                  // compiler wants this.

    throw flag ? new IOException("IO") : new SQLException("SQL");
}
```

Is it normal?

**Gratitudes**

I actually encountered this code when I was preparing a presentation for Java 7 features such as multiple-catch and typed rethrowal. Interesting. Thank you all for those good answers. I learned a lot.

**Update**

Java 7 has been improved for type specific rethrow, right?

```
void throwIoOrSql() throws IOException, SQLException {
}

void rethrowIoAndSql() throws IOException, SQLException {
    try {
        throwIoOrSql();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e; // Ok with Java 7
    }
}
```

It's somewhat silly the compiler can't see those obvious case.

```
throw flag ? new IOException("io") : new SQLException("sql"); // obvious, isn't it?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately, the compiler is not able to figure out that you can throw one of these two exceptions (and the language spec does not demand it).

What you have here is a ternary operator that returns an `Exception`. This can be either `SQLException` or `IOException`, but the only common supertype is `Exception`, so that's what the compiler will see here.

There are no "union types" in Java.

Same as in this case:

```
 Object x = flag ? Integer.valueOf(1) : "a string";
```

Here, `x` will also have to be an `Object`, because there is no other type to express `Integer || String`.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine, `?:` operator does the same thing any `boolean` value.

Answer (score 0):

Your synatx is invalid.You can do some thing like this.

```
Exception ex = true ? new IOException(): new Exception();
throw ex;
```

Answer (score -1):

This

```
b ? new E1() : new E2()
```

is a [reference conditional expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.3). The Java Language Specification has rules about how to determine the type of this expression.  The rule for your expression goes like this:

> - Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types `S1` and `S2` respectively. Let `T1` be the type that results from applying boxing
>     conversion to `S1`, and let `T2` be the type that results from applying
>     boxing conversion to `S2`. The type of the conditional expression is the
>     result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to `lub(T1, T2)`.

`lub` is [*least upper bound*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193918/what-does-lubt1-tn-mean) and, in this case, it resolves to `Exception`. Since you don't have a `catch` block for `Exception`, your compiler complains.

---

The compiler is complaining about

> Unhandled exception type `Exception`

because the `lub` (the type of that ternary expression) of `IOException` and `SQLException` is `Exception`. The compiler is essentially seeing, for example

```
private static void testThrow2(final boolean flag) throws IOException, SQLException { 
                                                   // this won't compile
    throw (Exception) new IOException("IO"); 
}
```