# What does lub(T1,... Tn) mean?

Tags: java, exception

The following quote is from

[**JLS 14.20**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)

> The declared type of an exception parameter that denotes its type as a
> union with alternatives D1 | D2 | ... | Dn is *lub(D1, D2, ..., Dn)*.

What is the `lub(D1,...Dn)` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stands for "Least Upper Bound" and is formally defined in [§4.10.4. Least Upper Bound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4):

> The least upper bound, or "lub", of a set of reference types is a shared supertype that is more specific than any other shared supertype (that is, no other shared supertype is a subtype of the least upper bound).

Answer (score 2):

It stands for *least upper bound*.  See [JLS 4.10.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4).